# Windows Ink Stylus Special Button Functionality Applications

Tags: windows, uwp

I am developing a prototype calculator application. In this application, the user will use an active stylus as the input. Lets use a Microsoft Surface N-trig pen as an example. I want the application to not respond to any input besides the Surface pen. Furthermore, I want the user to only be able to click when they click one of the buttons on the stylus. I was imagining a transparent layer between my underlying application and the user where the transparent layer would disregard any actions on the screen unless the button was pressed on the stylus, then it would capture that touch event and redirect it to where the user intended it on the screen, essentially redirecting the users input. I am under the impression that button functionality can be remapped in windows on a per application basis, am I correct in this assumption? Furthermore, is what I am asking possible? I have been looking into some of the pen API's (namely Windows Ink) but it appears that the InkCanvas and thinks like that are so the user can draw shapes and lines. What I am seeking is different in that I merely want the user to only be able to user the stylus as input (such as clicking a button on the calculator app) and only be able to make a click if the button on the stylus is pressed. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you want to realize this feature in the uwp app? And the Surface N-trig pen has multiple mode. which mode you want to use?

Comment: You can check for the PointerDeviceType for it being PointerDeviceType.Pen for example in any code that responds to events if you need button to only respond to pen input - ie. on the click event check for that type and then only perform the action when it's that.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: I want to test it first as a UWP app and then later as a system utility. Is what I'm describing possible to implement on a system wide level. For this example, I would like to use the eraser tool (for the surface pro 3 which is the closest to the nib) but I would like to get the ability to assign this functionality to any button on an active stylus as they have differing buttons. The surface pro 3 pen has three buttons and I would like to be able to do it for any of them, including the bluetooth button. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid: Could you point me to some documentation or example on what you describe? I'm having a difficult time finding some. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/ink-walkthrough) documentation?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT: I have seen the documentation but I don't want the user to be able to ink, i.e, draw and things of that nature. I want the stylus to be the only form of user input and the only means of interaction would be the stylus buttons. The user would tap a section of the transparent overlay where a button is and then the user would press on of the buttons and the transparent layer captures where the touch event would have went on the underlying system and then issue that command. So in essence, the transparent layer would capture the click and then issue it to the underlying application.